# Efficient way to Increment and push new value in document inside of a collection using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I want to save new doc if it not present in the collection based on words and if it is present then want to increase its count by 1 and push a new value inside of page. This one is working but i want more efficient way to do this.

My Current Approach: I think i am not efficient with my Code

```
my_model = new mongoose.Schema({
word: String,
count: Number,
page: [String]
});
```

// assume nextWord is a word coming from a wordArrayList using async.eachSeries and the below code will run for each nextWord and nextPage is the nextPage is the page which contains this nextWord

```
my_model.find({word: nextWord}, function(err, data){
if(data.length>0){
    my_model.findOneAndUpdate({word:nextWord},{$inc:{count:1}, $push:
    {page:nextPage}},{upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('updated!');
    });
}
else
{
    var newModelObj = new my_model({
        word: nextWord,
        count: 1,
        page:[nextPage]
    });
    newModelObj.save(function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('saved');
    });
}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `findOneAndUpdate` and `{upsert: true}`, there is no need for the outer `find`.

```
const wordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  word: {
    type: String
  },
  count: {
    type: Number
  },
  pages: [{
    type: String
  }]
});

const Word = connection.model('Word', wordSchema);

const words = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'];

words.reduce((p, word) => {
  return p.then(() => {
    return Word.findOneAndUpdate({
      word
    }, {
      $inc: {
        count: 1
      },
      $push: {
        pages: word.toUpperCase()
      }
    }, {
      upsert: true,
      new: true
    }).exec().then(res => console.log(res));
  });
});
```

Outputs:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  word: 'foo',
  __v: 0,
  count: 1,
  pages: ['FOO']
} {
  _id: 2,
  word: 'bar',
  __v: 0,
  count: 1,
  pages: ['BAR']
} {
  _id: 1,
  word: 'foo',
  __v: 0,
  count: 2,
  pages: ['FOO', 'FOO']
}
```